# PHP lines execute (MySQL commands) twice (or not at all once commented out)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database upgrade script which takes the current database version, passes it through a giant switch statement which *does not have any breaks* so all subsequent queries are run, then updates the database number to the latest version.

Disclaimer: I know there are probably better ways to do this (like just a bunch of `if($version>1507)` checks, so I don't have to have cases for "empty" versions) but I haven't had the time to refactor and test.  I will, eventually, but I really don't think this problem is related.

Here is a sample of the upgrades script, including the line(s) that are giving me problems:

```
case 1508:
    addNotification("Updating 1508: Adding feature specific tables for wake-up calls, virtual dispatcher and screen pop, to allow better usage and billing tracking", "success");
    dbQuery("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `feature_wakeup_calls` ( `feature_wakeup_call_id` int(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `employee_id` int(12) NOT NULL, `date` date NOT NULL, `confirmed` datetime DEFAULT NULL, `employee_sms_id` int(12) DEFAULT NULL, `employee_call_id` int(12) DEFAULT NULL, `authority_call_id` int(12) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'call record to the authority', `balance_id` int(12) NOT NULL COMMENT 'references balance table', PRIMARY KEY (`feature_wakeup_call_id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;");
    dbQuery("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `feature_virtual_dispatcher` ( `feature_virtual_dispatcher_id` int(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `inbound_call_id` int(12) NOT NULL, `outbound_call_id` int(12) DEFAULT NULL, `balance_id` int(12) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`feature_virtual_dispatcher_id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;");
    dbQuery("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `feature_screen_pop_endpoints` ( `feature_screen_pop_endpoint_id` int(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `mac_address` varchar(50) NOT NULL, `created_by` int(12) DEFAULT NULL, `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, PRIMARY KEY (`feature_screen_pop_endpoint_id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;");
    dbQuery("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `feature_screen_pop` ( `feature_screen_pop_id` int(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `mac` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL, `phone_number` int(12) NOT NULL, `format` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'ex: xml, html, etc', `when` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, PRIMARY KEY (`feature_screen_pop_id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;");
case 1509:
case 1510:
case 1511:
    addNotification("Updating 1511: New columns to the phone companion endpoints table", "success");
    dbQuery("ALTER TABLE `feature_screen_pop_endpoints` ADD `name` VARCHAR(200) NULL AFTER `feature_screen_pop_endpoint_id`;");
    dbQuery("ALTER TABLE `feature_screen_pop_endpoints` ADD `extension` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER `mac_address`, ADD `manufacturer` ENUM('Polycom','Astra','Mitel/YeaLink','Grandstream') NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER `extension`, ADD `model` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER `manufacturer`;");
```

The problem I'm having is that the `dbQuery` call immediately after 1511 fails.  If I comment it out, the next one fails.  Here is the dbQuery function:

```
function dbQuery($query, $returnId = false, $connection = null) {
    $close = true; // by default, close the connection once done
    if($connection == null) $connection = connect();
    else $close = false; // don't close the connection if it was passed to us
    if($returnId == false) {
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        if($result == false && !stringContains($query, "notification_log")) { // prevent infinite loops
            addNotification("Query Failed: ".$query." with error: ".mysqli_error($connection));
        }
        if($close) mysqli_close($connection);
        return $result;
    }
    else {
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        if($result == false) {
            if($close) mysqli_close($connection);
            return $result;
        }
        else {
            $result = mysqli_insert_id($connection);
            if($close) mysqli_close($connection);
            return $result;
        }
    }
}
```

Notice the `Query Failed` part.  My log says:

```
Query Failed: ALTER TABLE `feature_screen_pop_endpoints` ADD `name` VARCHAR(200) NULL AFTER `feature_screen_pop_endpoint_id` with error: Duplicate column name 'name'
```

If I comment out just that one line and start completely over (new database and everything) I get a similar error on the next line:

```
Query Failed: ALTER TABLE `feature_screen_pop_endpoints` ADD `extension` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER `mac_address`, ADD `manufacturer` ENUM('Polycom','Astra','Mitel/YeaLink','Grandstream') NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER `extension`, ADD `model` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER `manufacturer` with error: Duplicate column name 'extension'
```

Of course I checked to see if anywhere else created these tables (they did not, if I comment out the lines in 1508 they never exist) and there are similar `dbQuery` calls which are performing `ALTER TABLE table_name ADD` operations flawlessly.  For example, just a few rows above there is this:

```
case 1502:
    addNotification("Updating 1502: More data for the balance table", "success");
    dbQuery("ALTER TABLE `balance` ADD `extra` VARCHAR(500) NULL AFTER `method`, ADD `unique` VARCHAR(200) NULL AFTER `extra`;");
```

I have tested repeatedly, so I know it is something about **these lines** (the 1511 set), but I have run into this problem before and I had to re-baseline the entire database, bypassing the first ~1300 cases in the switch.  While that would work here it is treating a symptom and doesn't scale.

Anyone have any clue about what might be wrong?

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that the code you've shown here is only being run once? Debugging step: consider adding a `die()` or `echo` after your case statement to see if it's really running the entire case twice.

Comment: There is a `notification_log` table which is what those `addNotification` function calls hit.  I step through the queries and confirm there is only one entry per `dbQuery` call.  Once the error happens it's fatal and the script stops entirely.

Comment: Is 1511 a duplicate of any of the cases above? Do you have this query `ALTER TABLE feature_screen_pop_endpoints ADD name` ...anywhere else in your switch statement also?

Comment: I absolutely do not. Hence why if I comment out JUST that line the `name` field is never created at all.  Either leaving it in causes the `duplicate` error, or commenting it out causes it never to be created at all.

Answer (score -2):

I've got the same problem.
 [image]

And I found the browser always requested 'favicon.ico' after my php script. And It's Request URL is `{my_domain}/favicon.ico`.

**So It's Obviously the 'favicon.ico' request cause running the script again.**

Comment: I'm not even running the script from a browser visit.